# Sum of Banach valued Borel measurable functions need not be Borel measurable?

Tags: measure-theory, reference-request, banach-spaces, separable-spaces

Sum of Banach valued Borel measurable functions need not be Borel measurable when the Banach space is not separable. Any references to this result? Many thanks!

Comment: Does the domain also have to be a topological space equipped with the Borel $\sigma$-algebra, or can it be any measurable space?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See Theorem 2.16 in:
Measurability and Pettis integration in Hilbert
spaces.
Masani, P.
in: Journal für die reine und angewandte
Mathematik - 297 | Periodical
44 page(s) (92 - 135)

Comment: An (apparently legal) copy of the article can be found here: http://www.digizeitschriften.de/dms/toc/?PPN=PPN243919689_0297