# If $X,Y$ are independent, can we show that $\text P\left[X\in A,X+Y\in B\right]=\int_A\text P\left[X\in{\rm d}x\right]\text P\left[Y\in B-x\right]$?

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, independence

Let $E$ be a $\mathbb R$-vector space, $\mathcal E$ be a translation-invariant $\sigma$-algebra on $E$ (i.e. $B+x\in\mathcal E$ for all $x\in\mathcal E$) and $X,Y$ be $(E,\mathcal E)$-valued independent random variables on a probability space $(\Omega,\mathcal A,\operatorname P)$.

> Are we able to show that $$\operatorname P\left[X\in A,X+Y\in B\right]=\int_A\operatorname P\left[X\in{\rm d}x\right]\operatorname P\left[Y\in B-x\right]\tag1$$ for all $A,B\in\mathcal E$?

The result seems so obvious that I don't find a way to prove it.

Comment: As far as I can see, the main problem is that $X+Y$ needs to measurable (to make sense of the left-hand side). [This question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1162938/36150) suggests that there might be measurability issues.

Comment: @saz Good point. Honestly, I didn't thought about that. However, if $E$ is a metric space and $\mathcal E$ is the Borel $\sigma$-algebra (as in the question in the link), isn't $X+Y$ measurable, since $(x,y)\mapsto x+y$ is continuous? I guess we need to replace "measurable" by "strongly measurable" (in particular, assume that $X,Y$ are strongly measurable) in the non-separable case. In any case, if you assume for the moment that $X+Y$ is measurable, how would you show $(1)$?

Comment: There is a general result which says that for independent random variables $X, Y$ it holds that $$\mathbb{E}(f(X,Y)) = \mathbb{E}(h(X)) $$ with $$h(x) := \mathbb{E}(f(x,Y))$$ for any bounded measurable function $f: (E \times E,\mathcal{E} \otimes \mathcal{E}) \to (\mathbb{R},\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}))$. For $f(x,y) := 1_A(x) 1_B(x+y)$ this gives $(1)$, however we need for that the measurability of $(x,y) \mapsto x+y$; this measurability is not obvious, as far as I can see, for the general spaces you are considering.

Comment: @saz Don't you think what I wrote about strong measureability is correct?

Comment: I hadn't seen that you edited your comment. What do you mean by "strongly measurable"? What do you hope to achieve by replacing "measurability" by "strong measurability"?

Comment: Strong measurability is a notion occuring, for example, in the definition of the Bochner integral. It either means that the function is pointwise approximable by simple functions or, equivalent, is measurable (in the usual sense) and has separable range. The crucial thing should be the approximability.

Comment: I see; this should indeed allow to get rid of the problem of measurability of $X+Y$.

Comment: @saz What I actually want to show is the following: If $μ$ is a translation-invariant measure on $(E,\mathcal E)$, $κ$ is a Markov kernel on $(E,\mathcal E)$ with $$κ(x,B)=\int_Bq(y-x)\:{\rm d}μ$$ for some $\mathcal E$-measurable $q:E→[0,∞)$ and $X,Z:Ω→E$ are $(\mathcal A,\mathcal E)$-measurable, then $$\text P\left[Y∈B\mid X\right]=κ(X,B)\;\;\;\text{almost surely for all }B∈\mathcal E$$ if and only if $Z=X+Y$ for some $(\mathcal A,\mathcal E)$-measurable $Y:Ω→E$ independent of $X$ with $Y_*\text P=qμ$. I need $(1)$ for the necessity part.

Comment: @saz The measurability problem should not occur, since $Z$ ($=X+Y$) is assumed to be measurable beforehand. Or am I missing something?

Comment: If you are assuming that $X+Y$ is measurable, then there is no measurability issue; this assumption is just not apparent from the statement of your (original) problem. As I already mentioned earlier on, the assertion is quite easy to prove if $(E \times E, \mathcal{E} \otimes \mathcal{E}) \ni (x,y) \mapsto x+y \in (E,\mathcal{E})$ is measurable.

Comment: @saz Could you take a look at [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3140066/47771) question? It seems like that with the answers to [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3173795/47771) and [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3176173/47771) question we are ble to conclude, but I'm struggling to argue rigorously.