# If $(W_i)_{i\in\mathbb N}$ obeys the strong law of large numbers, what can we say about $\liminf_{d\to\infty}\frac1{d^{2\alpha}}\sum_{i=1}^dW_i$?

Tags: probability-theory, probability-limit-theorems, law-of-large-numbers

Let $d\in\mathbb N$ and $W_1,\ldots,W_d$ be mutually independent, identically distributed and square-integrable real-valued random variables on a probability space $(\Omega,\mathcal A,\operatorname P)$. By the strong law of large numbers, $$\frac1d\sum_{i=1}^dW_i\xrightarrow{d\to\infty}\operatorname E\left[W_1\right]\;\;\;\text{almost surely.}\tag1$$

> Now let $$\lambda_d:=\frac1{d^\alpha}$$ for some $\alpha>0$. I would like to conclude $$\liminf_{d\to\infty}\lambda_d^2\sum_{i=1}^dW_i=\begin{cases}-\infty&\text{, if }\alpha<1/2\\0&\text{, if }\alpha>1/2.\end{cases}\tag2$$

It might be crucial to observe $$\lambda_d^2=\frac1{d^{2\alpha-1}}\cdot\frac1d\tag3$$ and $$\lim_{d\to\infty}\frac1{d^{2\alpha-1}}=\begin{cases}\infty&\text{, if }\alpha<1/2\\0&\text{, if }\alpha>1/2.\end{cases}\tag4$$

By $(3)$, $(1)$ and $(4)$ we should at least be able to conclude $$\lambda_d^2\left|\sum_{i=1}^dW_i\right|\le\lambda_d^2\left|\sum_{i=1}^dW_i-\operatorname E\left[W_1\right]\right|+\lambda_d^2\operatorname E\left[W_1\right]\xrightarrow{d\to\infty}0,\tag5$$ if $\alpha>1/2$, and hence the limit inferior in $(2)$ is an actual limit and equal to $0$ as desired.

> Assuming that I did no mistake in my reasoning, how can we show the other case $\alpha<1/2$?

**EDIT**: As the claim seems to be wrong in general, assume that $W_i$ is of the form $$W_i=(\ln f)''(X_i)Z_i^2,$$ where $f\in C^3(\mathbb R)$ with $f>0$, $\int f(x)\:{\rm d}x<\infty$ and $(\ln f)'$ being Lipschitz continuous, $(X_1,\ldots,X_d)$ is a random variable on $(\Omega,\mathcal A,\operatorname P)$ with density $$\mathbb R^d\ni x\mapsto\prod_{i=1}^df(x_i)$$ with respect to the Lebesgue measure on $\mathcal B(\mathbb R^d)$ and $(Z_1,\ldots,Z_d)$ is distributed according to the $d$-dimensional standard normal distribution. It might be worth noting that the assumptions imply that $f(x)\xrightarrow{|x|\to\infty}0$ and $f'(x)\xrightarrow{|x|\to\infty}0$.

Comment: So what if $W_i \equiv 0$ for all $i$?

Comment: @PhoemueX Maybe I abstracted away too much of my concrete application. I've added the particular form of the $W_i$ I'm actually interested on.

Comment: You are implicitly assuming that $\mathbb{E}W_i = 0$? If $|\mathbb{E}W_i| > 0$ then this is much more straightforward than you are making this out to be

Comment: OP in general I think you would do well to edit your question. It took me a few minutes to figure out what you were really asking and I think this would be true of the other readers here. For the case where $\mathbb{E}W_i = 0$ for each $i$ [which is the only nontrivial case here], the crux is--put informally--*how quickly* $S_d \doteq \sum_{i=1}^d W_i$ goes to 0, as a function of $d$; how large of a power $\alpha$ of $d$ can you multiply $S_d$ so that $d^{\alpha}S_d$ still goes to 0 a.e. .

Comment: @Mike I didn't want to introduce too many (maybe partially unnecessary) assumptions at the beginning. In the particular situation described in the edit, we've got $$\operatorname E\left[W_i\right]=\int f(x)g''(x)\:{\rm d}x=-\int f(x){g'(x)}^2\:{\rm d}x$$ for all $i\in\left\{1,\ldots,d\right\}$.

Answer (score 1):

The [law of the iterated logarithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_the_iterated_logarithm) gives part of the correct answer.  Assuming $EW_i=0$ and $EW_i^2=1$, one has $$\liminf_{d\to\infty}\frac {\sum_{i=1}^d W_i}{\sqrt{2d\log\log d}}=-1,$$ from which the critical value of $\alpha=1/4$ not $1/2$ as you have it.

More generally, if $EW_1=\mu$ and $\text{Var}(W_1)=\sigma^2$, one can write 
$$ \sum_{i=1}^d W_i = d \mu + \sigma \sqrt{2 d \log \log d} \,T_d$$ where with probability $1$, both $\limsup_d \,T_d=1$ and $\liminf_d T_d = -1$.  Dividing both sides by $d^{2\alpha}$ gives
$$ Q_d = \frac{\sum_{i=1}^d W_i}{d^{2\alpha}} = \frac\mu{d^{2\alpha-1}} + \sigma T_d \frac{\sqrt{2 d \log \log d}}{d^{2\alpha}}.$$  From this one can read off $\liminf Q_d$, depending on the values of $\mu$ and $\alpha$.

Comment: @Mike Of course.  Thanks for the catch.

Comment: @kimchilover Do you think we can apply the same argumentation to the following question: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3140066/47771. Actually, this question is part of the other one.

Comment: That question is so complex-looking that I'll take a look later.

Comment: First: If $\alpha=1/3$ then $\sqrt {d\log\log d}/d^{2/3}$ tends to $0$, because $2/3 > 1/2$.  Not to $\infty$ as you seem to claim. Second: where in your problem statement (as opposed to your comments) does it say $EW_1<0$?

Comment: @0xbadf00d I believe what I wrote in my answer is correct, but I have ceased being interested in what your problem actually asks, and  whether my answer is relevant to it. I tried my best, but your notation and growing list of oh-by-the-way details makes it kind of boring.

Comment: Let me ask differently: Are we able to conclude something stronger? For example, $\lambda_d^2\sum_{i=1}^dW_i\xrightarrow{d\to\infty}-\infty$ in probability (in the case $\alpha<1/2$?